# Update query returns affected rows as 0 when the current value and new value are same

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Iam trying to update a value.

```
UPDATE val as u JOIN val as s ON u.id = s.id AND s.pd = 'xyz' 
SET u.pd = 'wxyz' WHERE s.id = 231 
mysqli_affected_rows() // returns 0 if s.pd != xyz  
                       // returns 1 if s.pd = xyz and updates the val
```

But this query returns affected rows as 0 when the current val and new val are same

```
UPDATE val as u JOIN val as s ON u.id = s.id AND s.pd = 'xyz' 
SET u.pd = 'xyz' WHERE s.id = 231
mysqli_affected_rows() returns 0
```

How do I make this condition to true ? So that it enters into the true statement block. Thanks.

**Update**

There is nothing to do with php code. anyhow it goes this way

```
 $sql_query = "UPDATE val as u JOIN val as s ON u.id = s.id AND s.pd = 'xyz' 
               SET u.pd = 'xyz' WHERE s.id = 231";
 mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)) echo 'successfully updated';
 else echo 'you have entered wrong value';
```

Comment: What _true statement block_ are you using? Please show your PHP code. This is documented behavior for [`ROW_COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) in MySQL.

Comment: Please also show the PHP code where you call `mysqli_query()` (or equivalent).  Really, this is a logic problem and reorganizing the query, error checking, and success checking will be the answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that is what my php code is

Comment: If you use [`mysqli::real_connect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php) you can set the `MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag, which should cause the call [to use the matched rows in the WHERE clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) rather than the changed rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is considered a feature of MySQL and a benefit in terms of optimization.  When the new values are the same as the old values, nothing is written to disk, nothing is saved to the log.

If you want to force a change, you could add a dummy column to the table and do something like:

```
UPDATE val as u JOIN
       pd as s
       ON u.id = s.id AND s.pd = 'xyz' 
    SET u.pd = 'xyz',
        u.dummy = coalesce(u.dummy, 0) + 1
    WHERE s.id = 231;
```

That would force a change to the record.